# Fluent-NHibernate - Component property attributes ignored by Convention

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, components, attributes, convention

I have a component with a number of properties that have various attributes

Normally when these attributes are added to a plain old domain object they are picked up by my custom AttributeConventions.

For the Component properties they are not. Is there some extra wiring needed for these?

e.g.

```
public class Component
{
    [Length(Max=50)]
    public virtual string Name {get; set;}
}

public class MyClass
{
    public virtual Component Component {get; set;}

    [Length(Max=50)]
    public virtual string Color {get; set;}
}
```

I get a table MyClass with columns Color & ComponentName

Color is an nvarchar(50) whilst ComponentName is an nvarchar(255) (the default)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK so relying on the built-in magic that ties the NHibernate.Validators LengthAttribute to the length of your table column seems not to be a good idea. The magic is that for bog standard classes this gets picked up by Fluent naturally. In order to force it I've created my own Convention to handle it:

```
public class LengthConvention : AttributePropertyConvention<LengthAttribute>
    {
        protected override void Apply(LengthAttribute attribute, IPropertyInstance instance)
        {
            // override the default column length
            if (attribute.Max != default(int)) instance.Length(attribute.Max);
        }
    }
```